# Silence calls from everyone but a defined set of numbers?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

If I'm on-call, I only want to be woken by important calls or text messages.  How can I set up an iPhone to ring during certain hours **only** for calls or texts from a certain set of numbers?

If it can't be done using vanilla iPhone apps, is there a 3rd party app that could do it?

Answer (score 7):

You could make a silent ringtone your default, and then assign other custom ringtones to each of that certain set of numbers.

See Apple's [Purchasing and creating ringtones FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1398) for a start.

Comment: I thought about doing this as an interim solution, though remembering to change it back when I _can_ be disturbed is not something I do reliably :/

Answer (score 4):

**2016**
This has changed significantly recently - posting this with iOS 10, but I think was available from 9, maybe 8

Settings > Do Not Disturb

You can set a defined daily schedule
This can also be toggled from the lockscreen, on an ad-hoc basis

Settings > Do Not Disturb > Allow Calls From >

You can choose by many criteria, Everyone, No-One, Favourites... or any specific group from Contacts

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you jailbreak, of course there's an app for that, several in fact. Search for "blacklist".